# Page scrolls in the middle on load

Tags: html, scroll, anchor

I don't know why, but when my page loads, i get scrolled in the middle, but i don't have any anchor aiming on this point...
Now i have to put a `<a href='MY-URL#top'></a>` anchor in every page for not getting scrolled on the middle...(Firefox don't even get them :0, -webkit browsers do...)
I have many anchor aiming on id's, and a  JQuery script for smooth scrolling, but no one for the middle scrolling of pages on load.

You can see that here :

http://www.groupae.be/ediser/2.0/nos_produits.php

What would fire that scrolling on load?

Comment: without codes, we won't know the cause.

Comment: the fact is that i dont have any code supposed to do that, i've checked all the scroll functions, all the anchors aiming to ID's...

Comment: You'll see that here :
(http://www.groupae.be/ediser/2.0/nos_produits.php)

Comment: its ok i found why i was getting scrolled, just the autofocus in the  footer form... :/

Comment: please put it as answer . thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its ok i found why i was getting scrolled, just the autofocus in the footer form... :/

Comment: Can you explain this a bit? I have the same problem, but am not understanding what you mean for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the page is long enough to have scroll and if you set focus on some element (for example for accessibility features), browser scrolls page in such way that focused element is in the middle of  the screen (if scrolls allows to do it, if not it will be scrolled as far as possible).

Comment: Little did you know that nearly five years later this answer would prevent me from throwing my laptop off of a tall building.